# How to share the error and not_found handlers in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am creating a web app using Ruby and Sinatra, and I'm splitting up the various aspects into separate `Sinatra::Base` classes, like so:

```
class Frontend < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    erb :home
  end
end

class Backend < Sinatra::Base
  get '/account' do
    erb :account
  end
end
```

Now I want to use the `not_found` and `error` routes, but I don't want to duplicate them in both classes.

What's the best way to declare them once and have them apply to routes in both classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SomeAwesomeClassName < Sinatra::Base
  get '/not_found' do
  end

  get '/error' do
  end
end

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  use SomeAwesomeClassName

  get '/' do
  end
end
```